# Физика автомобиля

Tags: unity3d, физика

Хочу реализовать аркадную физику автомобиля через rigidbody, есть масса автомобиля и его максимальная скорость и ускорения движения (Сила нажатия на педаль газа) от 0 до 1. Как можно рассчитать ускорение автомобиля исходя из этих параметров? И если необходимо какие необходимо еще ввести ? Физика обычная 2D вид с боку, без учета колес покрытия И так далее.

Update
Текущий расчет физики:

```
float acceleration = 100;
float force = acceleration * control.GetInput();
```

Comment: А где шаг изменения Силы нажатия на педаль газа от 0 до 1, я так понимаю есть еще продолжительность нажатия на газ T1, тогда сила должна изменяться от 0 до 1 с шагом 0,1 и шаг тоже может быть переменным!!!

Comment: Это понятно, тут вопрос к тому как реализовать физику с учетом веса, те чем больше вес тем длительнее авто ускоряется, Насколько знаю AddForce при использование ForceMode.Force учитывает такие параметры как Drag и вес, и если рассчитывать что сила равна Ускорение * Сила нажатия, то итоговая сила настолько мала что при модели весом 1,5 тона и максимальной скоростью 300 км не может сдвинуться с места, расчеты прикрепил к вопросу.